# Django Rest Framework update field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to DRF and I am trying to write custom view / serializer that I can use to update just one field of user object.

I need to make logic just to update the "name" of the user.

I wrote serializer:

```
class ClientNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientUser
        fields = ('name',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

This method is never called. I tried setting breakpoint there and debug it, but it is never called, even if I use PUT, POST or PATCH methods. If I add **create** method it is being called when I use POST.

This is how my view looks like:

```
class UpdateName(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = ClientUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientNameSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

Does anyone have some suggestion? Thanks!

My **models.py** looks like this

```
class ClientUser(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,primary_key=True)

    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[PHONE_REGEX],max_length=20,unique=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    member_from = models.DateTimeField('member from',auto_now_add=True)
    is_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The definition of what methods the endpoint can accept are done in the view, not in the serializer.

The update method you have under your serializer needs to be moved into your view so you'll have something like:

**serializers.py**

```
class ClientNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientUser
```

**views.py**

```
class UpdateName(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = ClientUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientNameSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.name = request.data.get("name")
        instance.save()

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Take note that you're overriding the [UpdateModelMixin](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L61) and you might need to change the above code a little bit to get it right.

Comment: Hi, update method breaks on this line:  `instance = self.get_object()`

Comment: This is the error that I received: `Expected view UpdateName to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the .lookup_field attribute on the view correctly`

Comment: @bla0009 how did you solve the issue? url keyword argument pk?

Comment: @momokjaaaaa the best way to update some attribute is actually if you use the queryset, so you can write for example  `Person.objects.filter(....).update(name="some name")`

Comment: Whats the different between override the update method inside view and inside serializers. ?

Comment: I know this is old but what happens if the serializer throws an error? The `instance.save()` is rolled back or It's left persisted in the database?

Comment: as the error suggests add the ```lookup_field``` primarily it is already set to ```pk``` you can update from what you are using like if you are using ```id``` then ```lookup_field=id```

Answer (score 6):

One other approach might be the following one:

**serializer.py**

```
class ClientNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
        model = ClientUser
        fields = ('name',)

   def update(self, instance, validated_data): 
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class UpdateName(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = ClientUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientNameSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data_to_change = {'name': request.data.get("name")}
        # Partial update of the data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user, data=data_to_change, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.perform_update(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use `class UpdateName(generics.CreateAPIView)`, this will only call a `create()` method on the serializer.

You should subclass `generics.UpdateAPIView` instead. And that's it.
You do not have to move your method to the view as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31175629) (it is basically copying/duplicating the UpdateModelMixin's update method)

For more information how serializers work regarding saving/updating [see the docs here:](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)