# how to use django Serializer to update an instance

Tags: python, django, serialization, request, updates

in Django PUT method, I want to update an instance:

```
sv= SV.objects.get(pk=pk)
serializer = SVSerializer(sv, data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
```

Here, in request.data, I just want to pass some of the variable of SV.
But as some fields missing, the is_vaild will be false.
What I want is, just update the fields in request.data, for the other ones, keep the value in sv.
How could I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework update field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173324/django-rest-framework-update-field)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perform a partial update by setting `partial=True`:

```py
sv= SV.objects.get(pk=pk)
serializer = SVSerializer(sv, data=request.data, partial=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
else:
    # Do something else
```

This allows a `PATCH` request.

**Edit**

If you want a default field during partial update (as requested in a comment) override the `update` method:

```py
SVSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): # Instead of exposing the 
    state_flag = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='sv_state', queryset=SVState.objects.all(), slug_field='flag')
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if self.partial and validated_data.get('state_flag') == None:
            validated_data['state_flag'] = 0
        super().update(instance=instance, validated_data=validated_data)
```

Comment: Thank you.
Then in partial Serializer, how could I initialize the variable to 0?
class SVSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Instead of exposing the state's primary key, use the flag field
    state_flag = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='sv_state', queryset=SVState.objects.all(), slug_field='flag')
Here, I want to set the defaule value of state_flag to 0 when partial Serializer.

Comment: Thank you. 
It still does not work.
Here is the error:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SV_STATE_KEY', table 'TEST.dbo.SAFETY_VALVE'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")

When calling validate, the error happened before calling update.

Comment: First check that you have set `partial=True` as in my answer. If the error persists, change your `state_flag` field in your serializer:  `state_flag = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='sv_state', queryset=SVState.objects.all(), slug_field='flag', default=1)`.

Comment: That means that default value is 1 right?